# ACCESS Insert Into issue , unable to update lot of values at once

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Data ([Region],[Office],[Employee Name],[Role],[Email ID],[T1 - New File Creation],[T1 - Roll forward],[T1 - Final package (PDF)],[T1 - Final package (paper)],[T1 - Efiling],[T1 - paper filing],[T1 - pre-season package (PDF)],[T1 -pre-season package (paper)],[T1 -FROR Checklist DESC Service check],[T1 - DT1 Intake and Initiate],[T1 - Scan and validate],[T1 - CRA website document downloads (Pulling NOA and other tax)],[T2 -New file creation],[T2 -Roll forward],[T2 -Final package (PDF)],[T2 -Final package (paper)],[T2 -Efiling],[T2 - Returns],[T3 - New file creation],[T3 - Roll forward],[T3 -Final package (PDF)],[T3 -Final package (paper)],[T3 - Net filing],[T3 -Paper filing])" & _
"VALUES ('" & Me.Region.Value & "','" & Me.Office.Value & "','" & Me.Employee_Name.Value & "','" & Me.Role.Value & "', '" & Me.Email_ID.Value & "','" & Me.T1___New_File_Creation.Value & "','" & Me.T1___Roll_forward.Value & "','" & Me.T1___Final_package__PDF_.Value & "','" & Me.T1___Final_package__paper_.Value & "','" & Me.T1___Efiling.Value & "','" & Me.T1___paper_filing.Value & "','" & Me.T1___pre_season_package__PDF_.Value & "','" & Me.T1__FROR_Checklist_DESC_Service_check.Value & "','" & Me.T1___DT1_Intake_and_Initiate.Value & "','" & Me.T1___Scan_and_validate.Value & "','" & Me.T1___CRA_website_document_downloads__Pulling_NOA_and_other_tax_.Value & "','" & Me.T1___CRA_website_document_downloads__Pulling_NOA_and_other_tax_.Value & "','" & Me.T2__New_file_creation & " ','" & Me.T2__Roll_forward & "','" & Me.T2__Final_package__PDF_ & "','" & Me.T2__Final_package__paper_ & "','" & Me.T2__Efiling & "','" & Me.T2___Returns & "'", & _
'" & Me.T3___New_file_creation & "','" & Me.T3___Roll_forward & "','" & Me.T3__Final_package__PDF_ & "','" & Me.T3__Final_package__paper_ & "','" & Me.T3___Net_filing & "','" & Me.T3__Paper_filing & "') ;"
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT Into Data ([T3 - New file creation],[T3 - Roll forward],[T3 -Final package (PDF)],[T3 -Final package (paper)],[T3 - Net filing],[T3 -Paper filing])" & _
"Values ('" & Me.T3___New_file_creation & "','" & Me.T3___Roll_forward & "','" & Me.T3__Final_package__PDF_ & "','" & Me.T3__Final_package__paper_ & "','" & Me.T3___Net_filing & "','" & Me.T3__Paper_filing & "') & "
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Data ([T4_T5 - New file creation],[T4_T5 - Roll forward],[T4_T5 - Final package (PDF)],[T4_T5 -Final package (paper)],[T4_T5 - Netfiling],[T4_T5 - Paper filing])" & _
"Values ('" & Me.T4_T5___New_file_creation & "','" & Me.T4_T5___Roll_forward & "','" & Me.T4_T5___Final_package__PDF_ & "','" & Me.T4_T5__Final_package__paper_ & "','" & Me.T4_T5___Paper_filing & "') & "
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Data ([T3010 - New file creation],[T3010 -Roll forward],[T3010 - Final package (PDF)],[T3010 - Final package (paper)],[T3010 - Paper filing])" & _
"Values ('" & Me.T3010___New_file_creation & "','" & Me.T3010__Roll_forward & "','" & Me.T3010___Final_package__PDF_ & "','" & Me.T3010___Final_package__paper_ & "','" & Me.T3010___Paper_filing & "') & "
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Data ([US tax -Letters(templafy & ms word)],[US tax -Printing/assembly(Dti)],[US tax - Printing/assembly(PDF)],[US tax  - Printing/assembly(paper)],[Us tax - Paper filing]) " & _
"Values ('" & Me.US_tax__Letters_templafy___ms_word_ & "','" & Me.US_tax__Printing_assembly_Dti_ & "','" & Me.US_tax___Printing_assembly_PDF_ & "','" & Me.US_tax____Printing_assembly_paper_ & "','" & Me.Us_tax___Paper_filing & "') & "
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Data ([USPT returns -Scan client information to pdf],[USPT returns -Printing/Assembly (CCH Axcess)],[USPT returns- Printing/Assembly (paper)],[USPT returns -Efiling],[USPT returns -Paper filing])" & _
"Values ('" & Me.USPT_returns__Scan_client_information_to_pdf & "','" & Me.USPT_returns__Printing_Assembly__CCH_Axcess_ & "','" & Me.USPT_returns__Printing_Assembly__paper_ & "','" & Me.USPT_returns__Efiling & "','" & Me.USPT_returns__Paper_filing & "') & "
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Data ([GES tax - Finalize and mail],[GES tax - Finalize and pdf],[GES tax - Scanning],[O&E submissions],[EL Draft],[EL Finalize])" & _
"Values ('" & Me.GES_tax___Finalize_and_mail & "','" & Me.GES_tax___Finalize_and_pdf & "','" & Me.GES_tax___Scanning & "','" & Me.O_E_submissions & "','" & Me.EL_Draft & "','" & Me.EL_Finalize & "') & "
```

When I tried creating only one CurrentDB.Execute to update values it is not happening. When I created multiple currentdb.execute it is only working for the firstone.

Can anyone please modify the currentdb code and help me out.

Comment: Are you trying to insert multiple records in the many fields of the *Data* table or insert a single row and then update values?

Comment: Curiously, too, if the `Me.` points to form controls, why not use a bound form to *Data* table and then use form to save the record?

Comment: Initial it was bounded form but it was also creating the same problem

Comment: What same problem? With bound forms you do not need `CurrentDb.Execute`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `DoEvents` command before each `CurrentDb.Execute` or, better, use *DAO* and the power of Access and open `Data` as a `DAO.Recordset`.

Then use methods `.AddNew` and `.Update` to insert the seven sets of values - it will run way faster and with much cleaner code than the multiple calls for `CurrentDb.Execute` and the SQL concatenating.

Comment: Can you share an example, am not a pro in coding and stil lin learning stage

Comment: A little searching will reveal the official docs: [Recordset.AddNew method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-addnew-method-dao?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: Thank you, I used the recordset method and it worked well.. Also I have connected table (Import and Export) to Sharepoint site. However when I use refreshlinks code. It is throwing 3009 error. Can any one provide some suggestions on it?

Comment: Currentdb.tabledefs("data").refreshlink - this is the code I used, but it is throwing 3009 error.